# Pandas - Indexing dataframes created with aggregator like .sum()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am ultimately trying to merge two dataframes together, but I am running into an issue when I try to specify the column on which they should be merged.

Using the following code:

```
total_payments_by_state = test_data.groupby('Recipient_State')['Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars'].sum()
```

I was able to aggregate a total dollar amount by state.

```
Recipient_State
AL                   245.55
AR                   751.22
AZ                  5455.80
CA                  6331.11
CO                   638.29
```

However, when I then try to index this to just see the variable `Recipient_State` with the following code:

```
print total_payments_by_state['Recipient_State']
```

I receive the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Recipient_State'
```

If someone could show me how to resolve this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `groupby` a column it becomes the index so you can either call `total_payments_by_state.reset_index()` so that it is restored back as a columnor access the index `total_payments_by_state.index`

Example:

```
In [2]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Recipient_State':['AL', 'AR', 'AZ','CA','CO'], 'Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[2]:
  Recipient_State  Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars
0              AL                           0.401242
1              AR                           1.333060
2              AZ                          -0.515762
3              CA                           0.740358
4              CO                          -0.900249
In [3]:

gp = df.groupby('Recipient_State')['Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars'].sum()
gp
Out[3]:
Recipient_State
AL                 0.401242
AR                 1.333060
AZ                -0.515762
CA                 0.740358
CO                -0.900249
Name: Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars, dtype: float64
In [4]:

gp.index
Out[4]:
Index(['AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO'], dtype='object')
In [5]:

gp.reset_index()
Out[5]:
  Recipient_State  Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars
0              AL                           0.401242
1              AR                           1.333060
2              AZ                          -0.515762
3              CA                           0.740358
4              CO                          -0.900249
```

Comment: Thanks for the help [again] @EdChum :-). When I reset the index, Pandas created a new column containing the zero-indexed row numbers. Is that a new index or is it just simply row numbering?

Comment: By default if you don't pass an index, pandas creates one for you so this could be what you see, but that shouldn't happen if you only have 1 index, it could be you called `reset_index` on the wrong object maybe the orig df rather than the groupby object